# Determine Whether Google 2-Factor Authentication is enabled for a User via API

Tags: authentication, google-api, verification, two-factor-authentication

I want to develop an application that uses Google as the authentication provider, but I want my app to know if the Google account is using 2-step verification before the account is enrolled in my app.

Can't find the required API in Google dev docs.

Comment: Related, maybe dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25603533/find-all-google-apps-users-not-using-two-factor-authentication

Answer (score 3):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25606130/2028774) here explains how to find out if users have 2-step verification turned on. See API documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/customerUsageReports/get) and parameters [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/usage-ref-appendix-a/users-accounts).