# Can you require users to have two Factor authentication via Google sign in?

Tags: security, google-signin

If you're building a site with strict security requirements and want to use Google sign in, can you confirm the user has some sort of second Factor authentication setup on their account before allowing the sign-in to proceed?

Comment: What you need is described here: https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-eap-acr-values-1_0.html
I'm not sure whether Google supports this though.
Also here to request an acr: http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#acrSemantics

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine Whether Google 2-Factor Authentication is enabled for a User via API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26314602/determine-whether-google-2-factor-authentication-is-enabled-for-a-user-via-api)