# Check google 2FA in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-api

I'm writing a chrome browser extension, and I'm trying to check if a user has **two factor authentication** turned on - is there an API for that? Should I just check a website that a user visits? 
I really don't know where to start here, a "let me google that for you" would also help me, because I can't find anything!

Comment: [How do I check if a user has 2-factor authentication enabled via Google Admin SDK APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26472157) ? At least I don't see any other way as well.

Comment: Yeah, but I kinda want the user to check his own status of 2FA - this API is for admins

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a user has 2-factor authentication enabled via Google Admin SDK APIs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26471069/how-do-i-check-if-a-user-has-2-factor-authentication-enabled-via-google-admin-sd)