# Is there any way to know whether 2 factor authetication is enabled for the organization using google SDK API's

Tags: python-3.x, google-api-client, google-admin-sdk, google-api-python-client, google-directory-api

I have access to google admin console. I want to know if there is any google API to know whether the 2 factor authentication is enabled or not

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if a user has 2-factor authentication enabled via Google Admin SDK APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26471069/how-do-i-check-if-a-user-has-2-factor-authentication-enabled-via-google-admin-sd)

Comment: Thanks for response but I have already gone through the same. The problem with this approach is, it's retention is just 6 months so for say , if I haven't changed my organizations 2FA setting for more than 6 months, I would no longer be getting any response

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the google directory api to check users 2fa

Look here:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users

It has:

```
isEnforcedIn2Sv boolean Is 2-step verification enforced (Read-only) 
isEnrolledIn2Sv boolean Is enrolled in 2-step verification (Read-only)
```