# How can I know google two factor authentication is enabled for a user for other google account?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

we are implementing a google auth in our application for sign in. We trust on google security and wanted to sign in users only have 2 factor auth enabled. We have users of other accounts which we don't own. We want to restrict everyone to have 2 factor auth. Does google provide a way to identify 2 factor auth for account other than we own?

I could not find any API which give me results. Please note that I have already checked following:
[Find all Google Apps users not using two-factor authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25603533/find-all-google-apps-users-not-using-two-factor-authentication)

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/usage-ref-appendix-a/users-accounts (it is for the same account)

[How do I check if a user has 2-factor authentication enabled via Google Admin SDK APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26471069/how-do-i-check-if-a-user-has-2-factor-authentication-enabled-via-google-admin-sd?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But that did not help much.

Please let me know any other information is needed from me.

PS: (Also please dont mark it duplicate because it is not for the same account I want to know if two factor enabled across different domain which has not answered in my wide search :) )

Comment: Did you ever get any traction on this/find out anything further?